# Admob Interstitial ad on Button Click

Tags: android, admob

I have an application and I am using admob banners to it. Now I want to show interstitial ad on Button click. 
My application have 2 activity, and I want to show interstitial ad on the second activity. Second activity has a button which goes back to first activity, and I want to show the ad after the button click. I am able to show the ad on button click but when the user closes the ad or press the back button it remain on the second activity and thats the problem I am facing.

SecondActivity Code:-

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


             if (interstitial.isLoaded()) {
                  interstitial.show();
                }
             else{

            Intent i = new Intent();
            i.setClass(SecondActivity.this, FirstActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
             }
        }
    });

}
```

I want when the user clicks on button the ad should be seen and when he closes the ad he should return to first activity

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you need is a `AdListener` for your `interstitial` that utilizes the `onAdClosed()` method to identify when the user closes the ad, so you can send them back to your first activity.

Your `interstitial` setup:

```
// Create ad request
adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
// Attempt loading ad for interstitial
interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);

// Create and set AdListener for interstitial
interstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
    // Listen for when user closes ad
    public void onAdClosed() {
        // When user closes ad end this activity (go back to first activity)
        finish();
    }
});
```

And your `btn` (button) setup:

```
// Create and set OnClickListener for button
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    // Listen for when user presses button
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // If a interstitial is ready, show it
        if(interstitial.isLoaded()) {
            interstitial.show();
        }
        // Otherwise end this activity (go back to first activity)
        else {
            finish();
        }
    }
});
```

This way if the user clicks the button it will either:

1. Have an ad ready and display it. Wait for user to close ad.

   Activity will then be closed through `onAdClosed`-method.
2. Not have an ad ready.

   Instantly close activity through the `onClick`-method.

Answer (score 0):

First:

```
private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
```

Second step:

```
mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this); 
mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.interstitialAd_id));
mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
```

Third step: button click event

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                mInterstitialAd.show();
            }
            else {
                finish();
            }
        }
    });
```