# Show Progress Bar on Screen before Interstitial Ad

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-fragments, admob

I am Working on Android Application that Implements Admob Interstitial Ad. What I want is the Handler Lock a Screen and Show Progress bar for two seconds and then Show Interstitial ad.

What I Have done is I animated the Interstitial Ad by Creating an Animation and Call it just After the `InterstitialAd.show` Method.

```
 mInterstitialAd!!.adListener = object: AdListener() {
        override fun onAdLoaded() {
            btnstart.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {


                if (mInterstitialAd!!.isLoaded) {
                    mInterstitialAd!!.show()
                    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.in_left, R.anim.nav_default_exit_anim)
                } else {
                    sharpref!!.privacyPolicyAccepted()
                    if (!sharpref!!.isFirstTimeLaunch()) {
                        val intent = Intent(applicationContext, SliderActivity::class.java)
                        startActivity(intent)
                    } else {
                        val intent = Intent(applicationContext, MainActivity::class.java)
                        startActivity(intent)
                    }
                }
            })
        }
```

The Code Animated the `overridePendingTransition(R.anim.in_left, R.anim.nav_default_exit_anim)` Interstiial ad but I want is Show Pogress bar for two seconds before interstitail ad opens.

Logcat After Crash

```
    2020-12-04 10:29:03.603 577-1239/? E/PackageManager: liangshuang2, setEnabledSetting, packageName=com.google.android.apps.youtube.mango,,className=androidx.work.impl.background.systemjob.SystemJobService,,,newState=1,,flags=1,,userId=0,,callingPackage=null
2020-12-04 10:29:04.309 577-5614/? E/PackageManager: liangshuang2, setEnabledSetting, packageName=com.google.android.apps.youtube.mango,,className=androidx.work.impl.background.systemalarm.RescheduleReceiver,,,newState=1,,flags=1,,userId=0,,callingPackage=null
2020-12-04 10:35:56.218 22376-22565/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-0
    Process: com.techpaliyal.bottomcutoutnavigation, PID: 22376
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't toast on a thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
        at android.widget.Toast$TN.<init>(Toast.java:405)
        at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:117)
        at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:292)
        at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:282)
        at 

com.maximus.technologies.views.activities.SplashActivity$setClickListeners$4$onAdLoaded$1$$special$$inlined$timerTask$1.run(Timer.kt:149)
        at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
        at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
2020-12-04 10:36:00.841 577-739/? E/UsbDeviceManager: unknown state HWDISCONNECTED
    
        --------- beginning of main
    2020-12-04 10:36:00.921 763-763/? E/licong: onReceive
    2020-12-04 10:36:00.929 577-596/? E/BatteryExternalStatsWorker: no controller energy info supplied for wifi
2020-12-04 10:36:00.942 577-596/? E/BatteryExternalStatsWorker: no controller energy info supplied for bluetooth
2020-12-04 10:36:01.171 577-596/? E/BatteryExternalStatsWorker: no controller energy info supplied for wifi
```

Updated Code

```
 btnstart.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {

        mInterstitialAd!!.adListener = object: AdListener() {
            override fun onAdLoaded() {
                
                if (mInterstitialAd!!.isLoaded) {
                    mInterstitialAd!!.show()
                    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.in_left, R.anim.nav_default_exit_anim)
                } else {
                    sharpref!!.privacyPolicyAccepted()
                    if (!sharpref!!.isFirstTimeLaunch()) {
                        val intent = Intent(applicationContext, SliderActivity::class.java)
                        startActivity(intent)
                    } else {
                        val intent = Intent(applicationContext, MainActivity::class.java)
                        startActivity(intent)
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun onAdFailedToLoad(adError: LoadAdError) {
                if (mInterstitialAd!!.isLoaded) {
                    mInterstitialAd!!.show()
                    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.in_left, R.anim.nav_default_exit_anim)
                } else {
                    sharpref!!.privacyPolicyAccepted()

                    if (!sharpref!!.isFirstTimeLaunch()) {
                        val intent = Intent(applicationContext, SliderActivity::class.java)
                        startActivity(intent)
                    } else {
                        val intent = Intent(applicationContext, MainActivity::class.java)
                        startActivity(intent)
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun onAdOpened() {}

            override fun onAdClicked() {
                // Code to be executed when the user clicks on an ad.
            }

            override fun onAdLeftApplication() {
                // Code to be executed when the user has left the app.
            }

            override fun onAdClosed() {
                if(!sharpref!!.isFirstTimeLaunch()) {
                    val intent = Intent(applicationContext, SliderActivity::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)
                }
                else
                {
                    val intent = Intent(applicationContext, MainActivity::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)
                }
            }
        }
    })


}
```

Comment: i do this in java using ```CountDownTimer```

Comment: @SaraGarcía I want is the Activity stuck and show progress bar for two seconds and then show interstitial ad

Comment: i think u coding in Kotlin. i don't know anything about it but here how to do that in Java. try to rewrite it in Kotlin.
```ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
pd.setMessage("Loading ad...");
pd.show();

new CountDownTimer(2000, 1000){
   @Override
   public void onTick(long p1) { }
   @Override
   public void onFinish() {
       if(interstitialAd.isLoaded()){
                   interstitialAd.show();
                }
               pd.dismiss();
   }
  }.start();```

Comment: Where Do I need to put this, Like I want to open Interstitial ad after progress bar for two seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53496168/12768366) answer for more detail on timers.

Quick Overview :-

The answer in the link shows different ways to schedule some work you have after a particular time. You can use this according to your requirements.

As much as I have understood from your question you can have somewhat like this :-

```
if (mInterstitialAd!!.isLoaded) {
     // show Progress Bar visibility here 
        Handler().postDelayed({
            //Hide Progress Bar visibility here 
            mInterstitialAd!!.show()
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.in_left,R.anim.nav_default_exit_anim)
            }, 2000)
   }
```

In this method after your `if (mInterstitialAd!!.isLoaded)` you can also have a timer(more details in the link provided) and then you can show your ad with your animation if you want.

Comment: I am Getting a Crash By Applying Handler

Comment: Please share your logs where you are getting crash.

Comment: My Scenario is Press Start Button Show Progress bar for two seconds and then show interstitial ad

Comment: Please post your updated code as well. Also why are you having your `btnstart.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener` inside of your `adLoaded` ?

Comment: have a look at this answer on how to show ad on button click :- https://stackoverflow.com/a/24601234/12768366

Comment: Yes I have Checked this Out, i want is Show A Progress bar before Interstitial Ad Opening

Comment: I have Updated My Code

Comment: In have Removed Btn_Start From the AdLoad Mwethod

Comment: @UsmanAli I don't see any changes in code. I am afraid i won't be able to help further without having look on code.

Comment: as you said you are getting crash by applying Handler I don't see Handler or timer in your updated code ?

Comment: Timer().schedule(object : TimerTask() {
    override fun run() {
        TODO("Do something")
    }
}, 2000) I have added this juust after the Onadload method

Comment: I have Removed that As It is Giving me Crash bUt i have Removed the Btn_start from the Above Onload method,just before I have Added these lines just after onload
Timer().schedule(object : TimerTask() {
    override fun run() {
        TODO("Do something")
    }
}, 2000)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225508/discussion-between-mohammed-hanif-and-usman-ali).